# Javascript onclick display multiple SVGs

Tags: javascript, svg, path, onclick

I am trying to display multiple SVG paths after clicking on a SVG polygon. I was able to get and individual path to appear onclick by using

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
```

getElementById() on works for one path though. How can I get the onlclick to work for multiple paths?

I tried using a for loop with getElementsByName(id) with plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/5u16eptq1YMSLeuVlya5?p=preview

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All id attributes in a document must be unique and you [can't use name attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName#Notes) in SVG so that leaves classes.

Replacing the id attributes with class

```
<path class ="test-arrow" d="M 1020 290 C1020,40 825,40 765,100" style="display: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 5px; fill: none; marker-end: url(#markerArrow);"/>
<path class ="test-arrow" d="M 960 385 C920,450 775,550 775,370" style="display: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 5px; fill: none; marker-end: url(#markerArrow);"/>
```

and using getElementsByClassName name fixes things.

Here's an updated [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ftIiZkuN0wtehnFiYrrH?p=preview)